# Login error message is showing on Url - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, message

I have an eshop, where there is a strange bug / issue.

In the login page, if you try to login with wrong credentials then, instead of showing the Error message to the user, i am getting the message in the url and seems like this:

```
http://example.com/my-account/?login=failed&wp-error=<strong>ΣΦΑΛΜΑ<%2Fstrong>.....
```

All the other error messages are showing correctly. 
Any ideas about this?

Comment: Please remove the html tags from the url  . here problem with your strong tag

Comment: Hello, i thing that the html tags are supposed to be loaded in the main page. But let's try this solution. How can i remove or edit the error message? I don't have code in function.php about this or overrided file in the child theme.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved.

It wasn't a bug from WooCommerce. This issue was caused by Page Restrict plugin.
When i disabled this plugin, everything worked fine.

Seems that there is a bug there that is needed to be fixed. 
In case someone else, has the same issue.